# Get list from input python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to form a list of **Strings** from an input. I've tried other answers, but they only work for numbers and only when there are no spaces in it. For example:

```
Enter input: ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]
["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]
```

or something similar. ( `Enter input: "Test 1", "Test 2", etc..` could also work)

Comment: You need to show what you tried. Contrary to what you may have heard, SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm sorry, but this is not a good question and will likely be closed very soon unless you edit it with an example of what you have already tried.

Comment: Have you checked out the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I get this every time >_< I coudn't do it myslef, because i'm not that good at python, so i tried everything i knew. I then searched it, discovering new things, but still leaving it unsolved. After sarching for a while, i decided to ask a new question. Contrary to what you may have heard, not everyone knows everything

Comment: Gee, do you think maybe you "get this every time" because on this website [it is expected that you PROVIDE CODE EXAMPLES of what you have tried,](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) even if they don't work?

Comment: @RickTeachey well, those code examples no longer exist, and i got my answer which works, so here:

Comment: Nevertheless, the SO guidelines very explicitly say that you should provide an example of what you have tried. It should be a trivial matter to produce something that doesn't work but illustrates more clearly what it is you are trying to do (which is why that guideline exists in the first place).

Comment: Rather than whining and complaining that people are asking you to adhere to those guidelines, maybe you should consider actually, you know, following them next time. As was stated above, SO is not a code writing service, and treating it like it is one lowers its value for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a case like this, you want [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval); as long as they enter a legitimate Python literal, it will work. [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) can also work, though it's less expressive than full Python literal syntax. Either way, you'd need to verify that it actually made a `list`, e.g.

```
import ast

bad = True
while bad:
    userinput = input("Enter text:")
    try:
        userlist = ast.literal_eval(userinput)
    except Exception:
        pass
    else:
        bad = not isinstance(userlist, list)
    if bad:
        print("Not a valid Python list")
# Once you get here, you have a legal list stored in userlist
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the other people were saying ""do not do this", ignoring it completely, while a simple answer could be more useful **Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

This way might be a bit more convenient:

```
N_items = int(input('How many items? '))
my_list = [input('Enter a list item: ') for _ in range(N_items)]
```

By the way: getting an answer does not mean it is a good question. There is a reason you are getting downvoted.